# .Click() freezes after file download in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, katalon-recorder

I've used Katalon Recorder and exported the C# code to my VS.

The thing that I noticed is, selenium acts inconsistently when there is a file download initiated (and finished) during the test case.

My test case works as expected until a file is downloaded, then Selenium for some reason skips the next `.Click()` method.
This has also happened when playing from Katalon Recorder directly.

It seems that somehow file download messes up Selenium and now I'm trying to figure out a workaround.

```
this.driver.FindElement(By.Id("button-next")).Click(); // Downloads the file

driver.FindElement(By.Id("button-back")).Click(); // Doesn't get executed or freezes here
```

Step-by-step works in debugger as intended.

Comment: Can you add a pause between the two? Maybe the browser actually freezes for a second while processing the request and the 2nd click is sent during that freeze.

Comment: Adding a thread.sleep(2000) helps but that's not the approach I hoped for

Comment: Can you add `html` for both elements?

Comment: @miramarska Agreed... but it's a starting point to understanding the root of the issue. Once you see that adding a pause fixes the problem, now you can search out better solutions. I don't know Katalon... does it have `WebDriverWait` or the equivalent? It may be as simple as waiting for the second element to be clickable before clicking it.

Comment: @miramarska Have you tried playing with various expected conditions: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html?

Answer (score 0):

you could try adding a try-catch and then retry the click:

```
try{
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("button-back")).Click();
}
catch{
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("button-back")).Click();
}
```

Or as @JeffC suggested in the comments, use a wait... or both a wait and a try-catch!